# Display Random Form On Page Refresh (in WP)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, refresh, radrotator

I am working on multiple one field forms to display in the footer of a clients website. Each time the page refreshes (like an adroator) a different question should be displayed. My clients CMS is wordpress so I'm using Ninjaform to create forms.

I have created multiple ninjaforms and tried to implement their shortcode and/or their php and neither will display properly, it just displays the code.

Seems like it is some conflict but not quite sure. Would like to find a simpler solution if there is one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you 'implementing their shortcode and/or their PHP'?

Comment: I was entering the shortcode or php (tried both) into the ad roators. The ad rotator would pull only one from the list but it wouldn't translate from php or the shortcode, just was the code.

Comment: Could we have some code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the result of a shortcode, you need to "execute"  it, which the ad rotator is probably not doing.

If you can insert text into the adrotator using PHP, you can execute the shortcode and get the results with:

```
$result = do_shortcode('[shortcode...]');
```

You can then insert the result.